# A question about independence of sigma algebras (generated by random variables)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ i.i.d random variables. Is it possible that

$$\{X_{n+1} \in B\} \in \sigma({X_1, \ldots, X_n})$$ for some $B$? Why yes/not?

I want to show that $\sigma(X_{n+1})$ and $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ are independent. Is it possible to have in $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ events that are not independent of $\{ X_{n+1} \in B \}$, for some $B$? Why yes/not?

Notation: $\sigma(X)$ = $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Thank you!

Comment: If $X$ are all constants, or $B = \Bbb R$ or $B = \emptyset$ that does indeed hold.

Comment: Why? (in my exercise, $B$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: I think proving this is a lemma in proving the greater result which is the Kolmogorov 0-1 Law? If so, try looking up proofs of that (eg Williams' Probability with Martingales).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If the event $A=\{X_{n+1} \in B\}$ is in $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ then $A$ is independent of $A$ hence...

(The exercise uses only the independence of the random variables $X_n$, not that they are identically distributed.)

Comment: Why A is independent of A?

Comment: Because $A$ is in $\sigma(X_{n+1})$ and $A$ is in $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.